# How can i set knowledge module option at run time?

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I need to be able to set LKM option at runtime, based on a value read from a table. I create a table in the work repository database that has 1 record per interface and a series of options. As the first task of the interface is should query the table (done that) and set the values in the KM options. Does anyone know how this can be done ?

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest solution ever, but if you have a finite amount of choice you could wrap several mappings using different LKM into a package that checks your variable and executes one of the mappings.

I believe the problem here is that if you were to have a variable in place of the LKM at design time, ODI would not be able to resolve even what options is meant to show you or how to compile in a scenario.

Comment: Came up with a cleaner idea, but you will have to build a LKM that contains all possible LKMs that you want to use.

In short: you create 1 LKM that behaves like all other LKMs, choosing which using an option. That option can be set using a variable.

Works at design time, works for compiling a scenario